# how to integrate iCal to iphone App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icalendar

i am new in iphone application development. I need to integrate iCal to an simple iphone app. is there any API or else to integrate iCal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look to [Event Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html) framework and [Event Kit UI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EventKitUIFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009663) framework but I don't know if it works on iOS version prior iOS 4.